# Why are Emitted Particle Objects Not Oriented Correctly?

Tags: particles

Im using a hair particle system on a flat plane, with a collection of people being objects I want to be emitted.  [image]

Even though the hairs of the emitter are standing straight up from the plane, the People Particles are all lying down AND are much smaller than the People Objects they are being instanced from.  When adjusting the Orientation Axis to get the People Particles oriented correctly (standing up), adjusting the Phase value to rotate them just makes them lean left/right or front/back, no matter which orientation axis I choose.  None of them rotate around the Z axis like i want them to (so that the people arent all facing the same direction)
[image]

I have three questions:

1. Why does blender do this?  What practical purpose does it serve to have the axis of the Particles changed and the scale be off from the Objects?
2. What do I need to do to have the Particle People oriented correctly and to allow for rotating around the Z axis (without rotating the the People Objects. this is just a pain, especially if i want those base people objects still active in my scene where they are)
3. Is it possible to change blender so that it emits particles in the correct orientation and size by default?  Its such a pain in the ass to have to adjust it by trail and error every single time (especially since i truly dont understand why this isnt the default)

Thanks!

Comment: Yes you need to rotate the particle on its local X axis to make it stand up on the emitter's normals, and also you need to scale it up if you want the exact same scale, I'm not sure why these choices, I hope someone will explain

Comment: Yeah, i was hoping there would be a solution  that didn't involve that, it's such an annoying seemingly-unnecessary step.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to avoid this is to use Geometry nodes, not a particle system.  A Point Distribution geometry node will do the same scattering, but will give you much more control, the scale of the scattered objects will be correct, and you wont have to rotate your initial object to weird angles/guess which particle orientation settings to use.

Watch Blender Guru's GUmdrop tutorial, he explains it well.